# How to collapse all the accordion by default in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i just need a little help about accordion. What I want is how can I collapse all the accordion by default when the page is loaded? My goal is to display all the accordion contents always. How can I do that?
Here's what I did in my code.

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
         collapsible: true, 
         autoHeight: false, 
         active: false 
      });
    });
  </script>

<div id="accordion">
              <h3>MASTER LIST</h3>
                <div>
                    <?php

                        echo anchor('category_controller/homepage','Categories');
                        echo "<br />";

                        echo anchor('item_controller/index','Items');
                        echo "<br />";

                        echo anchor('supplier_controller/index','Suppliers');
                        echo "<br />";

                        echo anchor('product_controller/index','Product');
                        echo "<br />";

                        echo anchor('#','Customers');
                        echo "<br />";

                        echo anchor('#','Depot');
                        echo "<br />";

                        echo anchor('h2morders/view','Reports');
                        echo "<br />";

                    ?>
                </div>
              <h3>LIST</h3>
                <div>
                  <?php
                        echo anchor('pricelist_controller/index','Price List');
                  ?>
                </div>

              <h3>HISTORY</h3>
                <div>
                  <?php
                        echo anchor('pricelist_controller/price_history','Price History');
                  ?>

                </div>

              <h3>TRANSACTIONS</h3>
                <div>
                  <?php
                        echo anchor('#','Inventory');
                        echo "<br />";

                        echo anchor('#','Material Transfer');
                        echo "<br />";

                        echo anchor('#','Material Return');
                        echo "<br />";

                        echo anchor('#','Disposal');
                        echo "<br />";

                        echo anchor('#','Order');
                        echo "<br />";

                        echo anchor('#','Delivery Receipt');
                        echo "<br />";

                        echo anchor('#','Material Issuance');
                        echo "<br />";
                  ?>
                </div>

              <h3>LEDGERS</h3>
                <div>
                  <?php

                      echo anchor('c','Items Ledger');
                      echo "<br />";

                      echo anchor('c','General Ledger');
                      echo "<br />";


                  ?>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: so you want the opposite from collapse? to show all tabs open?

Comment: your code seems to collapse all the tabs!  wonder what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

Add the active: false option [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#options)

```
$("#accordion").accordion({collapsible: true, active: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", false);
```

[Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active):

> Setting active to false will collapse all panels. This requires the collapsible option to be true.

Comment: I got an error when i debug it in console.log. Here's the error

Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on accordion prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Comment: @user2585508, you need to change the selector to yours accoridion, obviously.  `$( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", false);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "collapsible", true );
```

Comment: Ok i updated my code here' my code above. In included also the HTML file